# How to know the array reference value stored in memory?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a reference of the array that we assign

sup.

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

array1 = array 
array2 = array
```

now, array1 and array2 hold ref. of the **array** so my question is how to know that this 2 array holds which object reference? in a value ? in a pointer? memory location?

Comment: You can simply use equality operator`===`

Comment: Javascript doesn't expose pointers, memory locations or references. All you can do is pass objects around and test whether two variables hold the same object;

Comment: @CodeManiac I want the value of ref. a value that i can see === is not a value

Comment: @deceze  memory locations are not possible?

Comment: Nope. That is entirely abstracted away.

Comment: @Jigar value will always be same in all refs, for example `data` will always be same or equal to `array1` and `array2`

Comment: check this link may its helpful to you https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php

Comment: And yes, you can get stuff done in a language which doesn't expose details about memory, you just need to relinquish your C thinking.